# CSS for Safari 4.0 but NOT Google Chrome

Tags: safari, css

I'm having a problem with CSS. The style it's correctly applied in all browsers (IE6/7/8, Firefox 3+, Opera 9.5+, Google Chrome 3/4) but in Safari 4.0 it is not. If I use:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    #blaat { margin: 1px 0px; }
}
```

I can make work in Safari, but then it breaks in Chrome. Anybody knows of any Safari 4.0 specific CSS hack?

Comment: The bounding box is 1px taller

Comment: I've finally changed the DOM and was able to fix it. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to experiment with `line-height`. The default value for line-height is browser dependent so you can get different bounding box heights in different brwosers if you don't set line-height explicitely. For instance setting `line-height: 1.2em` (or 1.1em or 1.5em or whatever) should lead to the same height of the bounding box.

Comment: I've tried, but sadly I'm getting the same error, as both Safari and Chrome take the same line-height